# Is the "Offline browsing " a new feature in HTML-5

Tags: html, offline

**:::UPDATED:::**

i am reading about HTML-5 and what are the new features it offers, and one of these features are the **App Cache** which is define in W3school website as *"Offline browsing - users can use the application when they're offline",,*.

**But is this really a new feature in HTML-5 that was not avilable in earlier HTML versions??** since from long time (at least 6 years back) we have the option of browsing a web site even if we are offline since the HTML will be cached inside the browser ?? so what is meant by offline browsing in HTML-5??
BR

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is new functionality introduced with HTML5. This is **not** the same as your browser caching the site, such as the ole "save for offline use" option.

Some browsers offline caching mechanisms are simply just unreliable. HTML5 instead uses a manifest file to tell the browser what it should use for offline storage.

See:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

And the w3c working draft:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html

My favourite HTML5 resource (more regarding correct usage of older elements, and how to use the new ones): http://html5doctor.com/

Lastly, as many experienced web developers will tell you, **w3schools is trouble**. They're infamous for having all kinds of misleading and false information. See http://w3fools.com/

Hope this helps.